# Matlab: Optimization of reducing vector size

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have developed a function to reduce the size of an initial vector `X = [x,y]`. But for an `X` of 500,000 points and `points_limit = 10000`, Matlab needs 16sec to complete this function.

Are there any ways to optimize this, maybe by removing the loop using matrix operations (vectorisation)?

```
function X = reduce_vector_size(X,points_limit)

while length(X) > points_limit
    k = 1;
    X2 = zeros(round(length(X(:,1))/2),2);
    X = sortrows(X);
    for i=1:2:length(X(:,1))-1
        X2(k,1) = mean([X(i,1) ,X(i+1,1) ]);
        X2(k,2) = mean([X(i,2) ,X(i+1,2) ]);
        k = k + 1;
    end
    X = X2;
end
```

An other best idea is to have a new approach :

```
Ratio = ceil(length(X(:,1))/points_limit);
X = ceil(X);
X = sortrows(X,1);
X = sortrows(X,2);
X1=[];
for i=1:points_limit - 1
    X1 = [X1; mean(X(i*Ratio:(i+1)*Ratio,1)), mean(X(i*Ratio:(i+1)*Ratio,2))];
end
X = X1;
```

The objective is to reduce the number of points in a vector: a form of compression function for a 2D vectors.

Do you know if I can do this new method with loop ?

What do you think about my algorithm of compression ?

Comment: It would help if you described what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to reduce a too long vertor. For example, if the length of X= 500000, I want to can reduce in a length of 30 000 points without changing the vector

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really tell me anything. If you just wanted to reduce the length of the vector to 30,000 points you could just use `X = X(1:30000)`. Surely there's something else going on here.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily vectorize the inner for loop:

```
k = 1;
X = rand(5e5,2);
X2 = zeros(round(length(X(:,1))/2),2);
tic
for i=1:2:length(X(:,1))-1
    X2(k,1) = mean([X(i,1) ,X(i+1,1) ]);
    X2(k,2) = mean([X(i,2) ,X(i+1,2) ]);
    k = k + 1;
end
toc % Elapsed time is 1.988739 seconds.
tic
X3 = (X(1:2:length(X(:,1))-1,:) + X(2:2:length(X(:,1)),:))/2;
toc % Elapsed time is 0.014575 seconds.
isequal(X2,X3) % true
```

Comment: Maybe we can optimize too the while loop by do mean for more than 2 points in order to have directly the good number of points ?